# WPF Binding in a Style Help?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a style to a custom control that inherits from combobox that I can't modify.  Inside this style, there's a DataGrid control that takes in a ItemsSource, the DataGrid also has an x:Name that needs to get referenced in code somewhere, probably due to the event.

So basically

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

               ... A whole bunch of other stuff.

               <xcdg:DataGridControl 
                 x:Name="CustomItemOneGrid"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomItemOne_DataSource}}"
                 SelectionChanged="CustomItemOneGrid_SelectionChanged">
```

My problem here is that CustomItemOne_DataSource, well there's 3 times I'll use this control and well 3 datasources.  Also, the selection changed event I need to subscribe to also.  Is there a way to keep this in a style I can use across all three controls, but still have different Event and ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define attached properties for the items that can change that are not defined by the `ComboBox` class (eg. `GridItemsSource`). Then bind to those attached properties in your template. Much like I discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070421/wpf-styles-template-inheritance/7075046#7075046).

Comment: That should work :)  However, I still think I'm going to extract everything out into it's own user control, and just inherit from the other custom control.  I'll try both.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I let me DataContext flow down from the Control that is implementing the style / data template and then bind to a property on that control.  I wouldn't use StatisResources for your bindings.

Comment: Normally I would too.  Unfortunatly, this isn't code I can change due to it being baked into the application in HUNDRED+ spots.